# How to save image localStorage to database and server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, vuejs2

I want to save an image in local storage and then save the image to database and server from different page when user click a button.

Actually I want to take the image form user in product page and in checkout page when they click place order button, image will be saved in database and server.

So, I saved image in localstorage as DataURL and from checkout page I wanted to fetch the image from localstorage and create a hidden form in checkout page and set the input field value as the DataURL.

I'm using php as server side language.

Am I in a right track to do this?

Insert photo:

```
<div class="file">
   <input type="file" v-model="uphoto" @change="onFilechange($event)" name="photo">
</div>
```

onchange:

```
onFileChange($event) {
   let file = event.target.files[0];
   let reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = event => {
       this.uphoto = event.target.result;
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);

   //save to localstorage
   if (localStorage.uphoto) {
       this.uphoto = localStorage.uphoto;
   }
},
```

In checkout page:

```
<form id="myForm" action="">
   <input id="utext" type="text" name="utext">
   <input id="uimage" type="file" name="uimage">
   <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit form">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var utext = document.getElementById('utext').value = localStorage.getItem('usertext');
   var uimage = document.getElementById('uimage').value = localStorage.getItem('uphoto');

    console.log(uimage);
</script>
```

When I `console.log(uimage)` I am getting an error

> InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.

Now what should I do?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: try JSON.parse to get the localstorage item https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: Getting error after JSON.parse ```SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data```

Comment: And JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(your data)) ?

Comment: same error again.

Comment: In local storage the value of uimage is like this C:\fakepath\nature.jpg

Comment: @DutchPrime First off, don't link w3schools. Secondly, if `JSON.parse` didn't work the first time, running it again without changing anything is going to result in the same error.